# rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'hdf5r'

Tags: python-3.x, conda, rpy2

I wrote a `python` script (python `3.6`) that uses `rpy2`. `R` version is `3.5.1`. When I run `importr('Seurat')` it is giving me the error:

> /Users/kipnislab/anaconda3/envs/rmain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'hdf5r', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: Error retrieving current error handler

From which I see that `importr('Seurat')` needs to import `hdf5r` and it fails. I am working in a virtual `conda` environment. Launching `R` and running `library('Seurat')` works just fine. If I just open `spyder` and run `importr('Seurat')` it is also working fine, but when running in terminal: `python seurat_clustering.py` it fails with the error above. I installed `hdf5r` using `conda` and also inside `R` but it did not help. If I run `importr('hdf5r')` in `spyder` it gives an interesting warning that might be important here (not error though, so it loads actually fine):

> /Users/kipnislab/anaconda3/envs/rmain/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error: lazy-load database '/Users/kipnislab/anaconda3/envs/rmain/lib/R/library/hdf5r/R/hdf5r.rdb' is corrupt

Update

The question is still unresolved but I found the issue here. The following imports done one after another cause the issue:

```
import hdf5
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
seuratLib = importr('Seurat')
```

So, one file is importing `hdf5` to open up the files and load the correct data, but then I can not import `Seurat` because of that. I suppose there should be a way of unloading `hdf5` before importing `Seurat`.

Comment: Most likely an issue with conda and/or your installation.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I fixed the issue by switching the order of imports: first import all of the `rpy2`-related packages, then `Seurat`, and only then `h5py` (in a separate file that does data retrieval).

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
seuratLib = importr('Seurat')
import nice_service as ns
```

Inside of `nice_service` I had `import hdf5`